# How can you recover a different admin account password when the default Administrator account is disabled?

Tags: password, windows-sbs-2008, windows-sbs-2003

If I were to create a admin domain account on a remote `Windows Small Business Server (SBS)`, copy all permissions from the current `[default] Administrator` account, and then disable the `[default] administrator` account, then

**How can I unlock the newer admin account if it gets locked out (besides a full system restore from a BDR)?**

There will be no other admin accounts active on the server, but there will be standard user accounts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your domain administrator account gets locked out, you can still log in with cached credentials by disconnecting the server from the network much like you can log in when a password was changed. You will however be unable to access any network resources since that requires a check from the DC.

However, as this is a server ...I *strongly* recommend against deleting all local administrator accounts as you will not be able to log in as an admin in recovery mode. If it's a security issue, you're no more secure than using a network login as your administrator. Use a strong password.

EDIT: Safe mode will allow access to the local administrator account, so you can still get in regardless. Previous point stands though, don't disable it or else you'll have downtime!

Comment: I wish I could find the Technet article, but I'm almost certain that SBS uses the DOMAIN\Administrator account for various services/activities and disabling it can cause issues.  It's unique to SBS, but can't find the article that discusses it currently.

Comment: Oh btw, the DOMAIN\Administrator account is never fully disabled.  A reboot into safe mode will allow login of that account to then change/unlock the "personal domain admin" account.  You may want to include that in your answer as well as an option.

Comment: Ah, good catch.